# Did the Silk Road coins of 110,000 Bitcoins actually moved into Monero XMR during 2018 Sept?

Tags: bitcoin, speculation

There were reports of the Silk Road coins being moved into Monero XMR, which caused the XMR price to go over 20%+ over a 3 day period. Was there any proof of this happening or was it the cause of some other insider news to cause the monero price to move so much?

Comment: With monero's privacy, not sure how one could prove it.  Outside of the exchange(s) ratting out the person(s)

Comment: If those bitcoins did not move, then you can prove they did not move to Monero :) I thought these had been sold at an auction a few years ago though.

Comment: Monero got some positive outlooks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did not happen. The FBI confiscated the BTC and later sold it to Tim Draper. Here is the source: https://www.coindesk.com/tim-draper-revealed-silk-road-bitcoin-auction-winner